# Using demeanlist() to get lm() equivalence with weights

Tags: r, lm

My goal is to use `lfe::demeanlist()` to get a `data.frame` of demeaned data based on a set of factors. I'd then like to show that using this data in a simple `lm()` is equivalent to `lm()` with factors. This equivalency works without weights, but when I use weights the point estimates are off by a small amount. Using `felm()` and `lm()` is equivalent with weights.

**Sample Data**

```
library(lfe)
set.seed(12345)
iris <- iris

# Create weights
iris$w <- rnorm(150, 10, 1) 

# Quadratic term
iris$Sepal.Width_sq <- iris$Sepal.Width^2
```

**Equivalency between `lm()` and `felm()`:**

Notice point estimates `Sepal.Width` and `Sepal.Width_sq` are the same.**

```
# Simple lm()
> summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Width_sq + 
  factor(Species), data = iris, weights = iris$w))



Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                2.01987    1.31625   1.535    0.127    
Sepal.Width                0.96610    0.83626   1.155    0.250    
Sepal.Width_sq            -0.02736    0.13291  -0.206    0.837    
factor(Species)versicolor  1.45629    0.11285  12.904   <2e-16 ***
factor(Species)virginica   1.94694    0.10245  19.003   <2e-16 ***
---


# With felm()
summary(felm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Width_sq| Species,
data = iris, weights = iris$w))


Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
Sepal.Width     0.96610    0.83626   1.155    0.250
Sepal.Width_sq -0.02736    0.13291  -0.206    0.837
```

---

**Using `demeanlist()` to demean data and run `lm()` with weights:**

This gives different point estimates:

```
# demean and lm()
> newdat <- demeanlist(iris, list(iris$Species))
> summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Width_sq, 
  data = newdat, weights = iris$w))

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)     0.003732   0.035799   0.104    0.917
Sepal.Width     0.965895   0.830550   1.163    0.247
Sepal.Width_sq -0.027335   0.132007  -0.207    0.836
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. The problem with the point estimates was the `demeanlist()` function needs weights in `sqrt()` form because the model is estimating WLS.

```
newdat <- demeanlist(iris, list(iris$Species), weights = sqrt(iris$w))
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Width_sq, 
  data = newdat, weights = iris$w)

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -1.312e-15  3.580e-02   0.000    1.000
Sepal.Width     9.661e-01  8.306e-01   1.163    0.247
Sepal.Width_sq -2.736e-02  1.320e-01  -0.207    0.836
```

Now estimates are the same across model functions.

Comment: Did you find a way to apply "demeanlist" to an unbalanced panel (with NAs) without dropping the corresponding rows? I would like to avoid to do it manually.

Comment: @Bob Yeah I think you will have to do it manually. Maybe check out the `library(fixest)` which has a `demean()` that drops NA.